# Cannot upgrade software in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: apt, upgrade

After running `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade` reports many 404 errors for the updated urls.

```
me@me:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Calculando la actualización... Los paquetes indicados a continuación se instalaron de forma automática y ya no son necesarios.
  account-plugin-identica account-plugin-twitter gir1.2-ebook-1.2
  gir1.2-ebookcontacts-1.2 gir1.2-edataserver-1.2 gir1.2-messagingmenu-1.0
  gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 libntdb1 linux-image-4.2.0-19-generic
  linux-image-4.2.0-21-generic linux-image-4.2.0-22-generic
  linux-image-4.2.0-23-generic linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic
  linux-image-4.2.0-27-generic linux-image-4.2.0-34-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-19-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-21-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-22-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-23-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-25-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-27-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-34-generic python-ntdb
Utilice «apt-get autoremove» para eliminarlos.
Listo
Se actualizarán los siguientes paquetes:
  firefox firefox-locale-en firefox-locale-es thunderbird-globalmenu
4 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 0 no actualizados.
Se necesita descargar 47,0 MB de archivos.
Se utilizarán 12,3 kB de espacio de disco adicional después de esta operación.
¿Desea continuar? [S/n] 
Err http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu/ wily-security/main firefox amd64 46.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.15.10.2
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu/ wily-security/main firefox-locale-en amd64 46.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.15.10.2
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu/ wily-security/main firefox-locale-es amd64 46.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.15.10.2
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu/ wily-security/universe thunderbird-globalmenu amd64 1:38.8.0+build1-0ubuntu0.15.10.1
  404  Not Found
E: Fallo al obtener http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox_46.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.15.10.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Fallo al obtener http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox-locale-en_46.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.15.10.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Fallo al obtener http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox-locale-es_46.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.15.10.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Fallo al obtener http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/thunderbird/thunderbird-globalmenu_38.8.0+build1-0ubuntu0.15.10.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: No se pudieron obtener algunos archivos, ¿quizás deba ejecutar «apt-get update» o deba intentarlo de nuevo con --fix-missing?
```

What can I do to make it work? (using `--fix-missing` didn't change anything).

[Answers in this question did not help me](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists).

**Additional background**: Yesterday my connection broke while trying to update Ubuntu. My connection broke in the download stage. I was trying now to update the packages and distribution, but I am getting these errors.

Answer (score 1):

did you try `apt-get -f install`?

The Link "http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu/ wily-security/main" does not exist on my computer either.

However "http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu/dists/wily-security/main" exists.

Maybe you have to change the links in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or inside the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Comment: Will try when back home and tell you :). Btw this is not a link: http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu/ wily-security/main. They are two parts out of 4 that render the actual links. But anyway will try it to see if it works.